# How to control the height of the template in Wpf

Tags: wpf, validation, templates, styles

I working on a style for text box that show red border, an error image and error text on a new line.
It works if it has space on the bottom the text box like the picture below.
[image: Style1]

If below the validating text box has other control, then I cannot see the icon and error text.

[image: Style2]

What is the best way to fix this template?

```
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Grid x:Name="errorBlock" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0,2,0,-30" Z>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Error.png"  Height="14" Width="14"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"  TargetName="errorBlock" Value="Visible" />                           
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use -30 on Margin - it can produce some unexpected behavior. I'd rather use a two-row Grid instead of StackPanel and set the second row height to Auto with Visibility="Collapsed".

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Bd" >
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
            </Border>
            <Grid x:Name="errorBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="14" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="Error.png" Height="14" Width="14" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"  />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility"  TargetName="errorBlock" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```